# Combine multiple file with similar prefix

Tags: python

I have multiple files like

```
file_rank0_1011.pt
file_rank0_1332.pt
file_rank1_1456.pt
file_rank1_1178.pt
file_rank1_1111.pt
file_rank2_4511.pt
file_rank2_1111.pt
file_rank2_1111.pt
file_rank3_1451.pt
file_rank3_1134.pt
```

I want to combine the files rank wise with unique name. i.e., all files with `file_rankN_****` will combine
eg.

```
file_rank0_combine.pt
file_rank1_combine.pt
file_rank2_combine.pt
file_rank3_combine.pt
```

How can we do that in python?

Comment: your question is not clear. What are these file types? How do you want the combination? Do the files go inside the combine folder? Please update your question with details outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You want one "_combine" per unique prefix ? is that the exact output you want ?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with file type.

Comment: Hi @mona Take a look at this repo i have created as working example. It may be what you are looking for.
https://github.com/bkglobal/python_rank_based_file_mapper_script

Comment: How do you *"combine"* the files? Do they need sorting and merging? Concatenating? Deconstructing and reconstructing?

Comment: They need to take a look at all the files in folder and combine on the basis of file_rank<RANK>... So file content will be merged on the basis of rank..

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```py
files = [
    'file_rank0_1011',
    'file_rank0_1332',
    'file_rank1_1456',
    'file_rank1_1178',
    'file_rank1_1111',
    'file_rank2_4511',
    'file_rank2_1111',
    'file_rank2_1111',
    'file_rank3_1451',
    'file_rank3_1134'
]
mapper = dict()
for file in files:
    prefix = file.split('_')[1]
    if prefix not in mapper.keys():
        mapper[prefix] = [file]
    else:
        mapper[prefix].append(file)
mapper
```

```bash
{'rank0': ['file_rank0_1011', 'file_rank0_1332'],
 'rank1': ['file_rank1_1456', 'file_rank1_1178', 'file_rank1_1111'],
 'rank2': ['file_rank2_4511', 'file_rank2_1111', 'file_rank2_1111'],
 'rank3': ['file_rank3_1451', 'file_rank3_1134']}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: yes, will have to combine the files/items in dictionary

Comment: Hi PatioFurnitureIsCool and mona. My answer was intended to abstract the complexity of reading from disk as well as processing the combination. I understood that the user's difficulty is to separate the files of the same ranking.

Answer (score 0):

To combine files based on their rank, first loop through all the files in the directory, then identify their rank by parsing their filenames and finally for each rank, combine the contents of the files and write to the combined file.

```
import os
import re

# Directory where the files are located
directory_path = 'path_to_directory'

# Create a dictionary to store the contents of files for each rank
ranked_files = {}

# Loop through each file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    # Use regex to match the pattern and extract the rank
    match = re.match(r'file_rank(\d+)_\d+', filename)
    if match:
        rank = match.group(1)
        # Append the content to the appropriate rank in the dictionary
        with open(os.path.join(directory_path, filename), 'r') as f:
            if rank not in ranked_files:
                ranked_files[rank] = []
            ranked_files[rank].append(f.read())

# Create the combined files
for rank, contents in ranked_files.items():
    combined_filename = os.path.join(directory_path, f'file_rank{rank}_combine')
    with open(combined_filename, 'w') as f:
        # Join the contents and write to the file
        f.write("\n".join(contents))

print("Files combined successfully.")
```

Make sure to replace `'path_to_directory'` with the actual path to the directory where the files are located. This script will combine the files rank-wise and create new files with the `_combine` suffix. Also this script does not delete the copied files, so that is something you might want to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it using similar prefix using python script.

```
import os
import sys
import re

def combine_files(folder_path):
    # Get a list of all files in the specified folder
    files = os.listdir(folder_path)

    # Create a dictionary to store file contents by rank
    file_contents_by_rank = {}

    # Iterate through the files and organize them by rank
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.startswith("file_rank"):
            match = re.match(r"file_rank(\d+)_(\w+)", file_name)
            if match:
                rank = int(match.group(1))
                
                with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), "r") as file:
                    content = file.read()
                    
                if rank not in file_contents_by_rank:
                    file_contents_by_rank[rank] = []
                file_contents_by_rank[rank].append(content)

    # Create the 'updated_dump_files' folder if it doesn't exist
    updated_folder_path = os.path.join("updated_dump_files")
    os.makedirs(updated_folder_path, exist_ok=True)

    # Combine and save files by rank
    for rank, contents in file_contents_by_rank.items():
        combined_content = "\n".join(contents)
        combined_file_name = f"file_rank{rank}_combine.txt"

        with open(
            os.path.join(updated_folder_path, combined_file_name), "w"
        ) as combined_file:
            combined_file.write(combined_content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 or sys.argv[1].lower() != "combine":
        print("Usage: python main.py combine")
    else:
        folder_path = "dump_files"  # Update this with the actual path to your folder
        combine_files(folder_path)
```

Save this code in a file named main.py in the same directory where your dump_files folder is located. Then, open a terminal and navigate to the directory containing main.py. Run the command:

```
python main.py combine
```

combine or any word you like.

Here is working example as well in this github repo.
https://github.com/bkglobal/python_rank_based_file_mapper_script

Thanks.